# Installing vagrant-vsphere plugin

Tags: plugins, development-environment, vagrant, puppet, vsphere

so I recently installed the vagrant-aws plugin with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws`, after quite the adventure with ruby versions and dependencies. Anyway, for our deployment pipeline I need to find a way to spin up vSphere machines with vagrant, and there is a [vagrant-vsphere plugin on github](https://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere), but I have no idea what to do with it. I'm really new to ruby/programming/devOps in general, and it doesn't look like vagrant will allow you to install plugins from local files.

I saw in the vagrant docs you can require a plugin in your vagrant file with require 'my_plugin', and I tried the path to the .gemspec file where my_plugin is, but can't seem to figure out how to work this. If anyone has help or pointers to places on the internet I can look, I would very much appreciate it :) I'll be scouring the web for a long time to find a solution.

Comment: Did you try `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vsphere` ?

Comment: yes, I did, sorry should have mentioned that (was the first thing I tried)

Comment: And ... ? I mean, why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't believe it's in their official repos 'The plugin 'vagrant-vsphere' could not be found in local or remote repositories. Please check the name of the plugin and try again'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install it after bulding it from source:

```
mkdir ~/tmpbuild
cd ~/tmpbuild
git clone git://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere.git
cd vagrant-vsphere
gem build vSphere.gemspec
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vsphere-0.0.1
```

Comment: This worked, but didn't seem to actually install the vagrant-vsphere plugin, but after I ran vagrant plugin install vagrant-vsphere after running all your previous commands it allowed me to install it and it worked! Trying to bring up a dummy box, but having problems with that. I believe this is problem solved!

Comment: Note: after running vagrant plugin install vagrant-vsphere the first time, it said "Installed the plugin 'mini_portile (0.5.0)'!", and did not install the provider, but the second time running the command yielded "Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vsphere (0.0.1)'!